# Can I use Bonjour from command line?

Tags: networking, bonjour, zeroconf

Is it possible to use Bonjour from command line? For example if I want to register a service I type something like that: bonjour -register service_name port. And then Bonjour allocate a free IP for my service. Or, for example, if I want to see a list of available services I type something like: bonjour -showServices. And then I get list of all available services with their names, IP addresses and ports. Does something like that exist?

I am kind of confused by the available documentation. For example [here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Articles/registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002478-SW1), in the beginning of the document I see:

> To register your service, call
>   DNSServiceRegister.

Where should I call it? In the command line? In Java? In C++? In python? It is kind of strange that this kind of context is not provided.

In general, I find just a general information about zeroconf and Bonjour (what it is supposed to do). But I cannot find something concrete and simple. Like "Hello World" examples of usage of Bonjour.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. They help but Is still did not get the answer on my question: "Can I use Bonjour from command line?". Max, mDNS is not not for Windows (which I need). jdizzle, dns-sd is very close to what I need but it is not Bonjour, right? May be dns-sd is used by Bonjour?

Comment: I found an example of a real-world use of Bonjour from the command line, to advertise a printer on another machine that doesn't support mDNS. You might find it answers some of your questions:
http://playcontrol.net/ewing/jibberjabber/advertising_a_legacy_networ.html

Comment: dns-sd is a command line tool to register/browse bonjour announcements.  It is exactly what you say you want, but I bet what you really want is a bonjour API for your application to use, which also exist.

Answer (score 30):

`dns-sd` is the command line program that works on both windows and Mac OS X.

I often use it to tunnel iTunes shares over the internet with ssh. My typical use is `dns-sd -P my_music _daap._tcp. local 3690 localhost 127.0.0.1`.  This assumes that I've set up an ssh tunnel listen on localhost port 3690 to port 3689 of the host sharing iTunes on the foreign network.  This makes a little iTunes share icon appear in iTunes named "my_music".

Answer (score 6):

mDNS is an older version of the dns-sd tool. They are both command line tools, written by Apple, to interact with Bonjour.

You can use the command line tool to do a few things with Bonjour, but to quote from the dns-sd man page:

> The dns-sd command is primarily intended for interactive use.  Because its command-line arguments and output format are subject to change, invoking it from a shell script will generally be fragile.
>
> If you wish to perform DNS Service Discovery operations from a scripting language, then the best way to do this is not to execute the dns-sd command and then attempt to decipher the textual output, but instead to directly call the DNS-SD APIs using a binding for your chosen language.
>
> For example, if you are programming in Ruby, then you can directly call DNS-SD APIs using the dnssd package documented at http://rubyforge.org/projects/dnssd/.
>   Similar bindings for other languages are also in development.

For example, you asked about "DNSServiceRegister", which is a C function:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/dns_sd_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DNSServiceRegister

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible. Take a look at the man page for [mDNS](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mDNS.1.html)

Comment: But I think mDNS is for Mac OS, isn't? I need to use Windows XP.

Comment: Buy the way, is mDNS a part of Bonjour? Or, how mDNS and Bonjour are related?

Comment: Yes, mDNS is a Mac OS/UNIX program. mDNS is a part of Bonjour (what used to be called Rendezvous) which is Apple's implementation of Zeroconf networking. Take a look at the reference material on Apple's website: http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/index.html.

Comment: Is there something similar for Windows?

Comment: I'm not sure if the command-line tools are part of Apple's Bonjour for Windows. Why not download it & check? If you sign up for a (free) ADC account, I believe you can download source code as well.

Comment: I have just installed Bonjour on my Windows. After that I tired "mDNS" in the command line and the command was not found. But in the "Program Files\Bonjour" I found "mDNSResponder.exe". I do not know if it is the same.

Comment: No it's not the same - that is the daemon that listens for mDNS queries and responds to them. There is a good video talk by Stuart Cheshire, the inventor of zeroconf networking, explaining how it all works here:
http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-7398680103951126462#
(I discovered Stuart Cheshire went to the same school as I did!)

Comment: @Max - Link dead, looks like this one may be same thing? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhtZJ6EsCXo