# AS3 and Bonjour

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bonjour

Is it possible to get bonjour running in as3 in flash?

Comment: Service location application (like printers and such) by apple.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fair bit of digging the answer is no flash does not support bonjour as of 21/3/2011.

bonjour utilities UDP which the flash player has just starting supporting as of 10.0 so maybe one day.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I've not seen anyone do that and i'm not familiar with Apple's APIs, but I can tell you that if you're building an AIR 2.5 application you have access to the NativeProcess API, which essentially allows you to execute Command Line commands from inside of your application.

It seems like you might be able to then apply that to something like this: [Can I use Bonjour from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379413/can-i-use-bonjour-from-command-line)

Let me know if that makes sense. If you're not using AIR you'd have to jump through some hoops on your server side, but if you're connecting to PHP or whatever then you can just as easily call command line methods from there.

If you have any questions let me know!

Comment: i really wana get it running in flash as this only requirement that would need air then i could probably go with out, if its not possible...after a little more digging it seems that bonjour uses UDP...last thing heard udp is available in flash player 10+ its just that there are no libraries i can find that support it :(  thx :)