# How to list AFP shares from command-line (MacOS)?

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, afp

From the command-line, I need to list all the AFP shares available from a given server on a local network.

I can browse the available servers that provides AFP as follow:

```
iMac:bin me$ dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp
Browsing for _afpovertcp._tcp
Timestamp     A/R Flags if Domain                    Service Type              Instance Name
10:36:36.531  Add     3  4 local.                    _afpovertcp._tcp.         iMac
10:36:36.547  Add     3  5 local.                    _afpovertcp._tcp.         iMac
10:36:36.547  Add     3  4 local.                    _afpovertcp._tcp.         box
10:36:36.547  Add     2  5 local.                    _afpovertcp._tcp.         box
^C
```

And now I want to know what shares are available from "iMac" for instance (the ones that are displayed by the Finder when you clic on the server icon in the "Shares" left-column view) ?

PS I already found many threads about this ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/376914/how-to-list-network-shared-items-in-terminal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379413/can-i-use-bonjour-from-command-line)), but they are unanswered for this specific topic.

Answer (score 2):

Have alook at this one:

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/afp-showmount.html

I could get the info about available afp-shares with nmap...

My command:

nmap -p 548 --script afp-showmount --script-args afp.username=*yourusername*,afp.password=*yourpassword* *yourserveraddress*

Comment: Is there a way to modify that to get all local AFP shares, eg: not a specific host?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here looking for this answer:

```
sudo sharing -l
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, either you want the list of the mounted afp shares, then you can issue a mount command and you will get something like:

```
//someUser@someServer._afpovertcp._tcp.local/path on /Volumes/path (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by someUser)
```

Or you want to know what shares could be available for mounting… and unfortunately that's not easy since you first need to log in as a user to list the available shares for you to mount. Different users may see different shares for the same server.